# ios10 : Unable to select anything after interaction with native dropdown

Tags: ios, html-select, ios10, selectboxit

I have a Responsive solution which consumes HTML 'Select' Tag. This when opened in Safari (in IOS10) , allows me to select any value from dropdown.

Once I interacted with native dropdown, when I tap anywhere on the web page again triggers the native dropdown. I checked this behaviour across multiple websites, I was able to reproduce in some of them.

This is causing major issue as the overall journey is halted.

Appreciate if you have come across such issue ,please provide pointers around the same

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did a work around this ( may not be a optimum solution) though.

on change of select , focus out the element.

```
<select onchange="this.blur()"></select>
```